# How to create table with expandable/collapsible rows in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I'm trying to display some data in a table format where each row can expand vertically to reveal additional information.

Let's say for the sake of an example that this is a list of books, where the initially visible rows have columns for title, author, etc.

Then, when a row is selected, it expands vertically and displays a new area underneath with a single cell (spanning the width of the row) that contains a long, text description of the book.

Basically, when the second row is selected I'd like something with approximately this structure:

[image: HTML version of table]

I can do the table part easily with a DataGridView or with a ListView set to Details, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the row expanding part.

Is there some way to do this or, at least, something that looks like this to the user?

I would prefer to avoid using 3rd party libraries, if possible.

Comment: What type of user interface-- web page, WPF, WinForms, or what?

Comment: Using CSS/jquery would be your easiest bet here

Comment: @JohnWu Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the expandable/collapsible rows in a C# DataGridView is to use the RowTemplate property of the DataGridView and customize it to include a panel control that can be expanded and collapsed.

```
// Create a DataGridView control
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

// Set the RowTemplate property to customize the rows
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 50;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft;

// Add a panel control to the RowTemplate
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel.Visible = false;
panel.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Controls.Add(panel);

// Add an event handler for the RowStateChanged event to handle row selection
dataGridView1.RowStateChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index];
        Panel p = (Panel)row.Cells[0].OwningRow.Template.Controls[0];
        p.Visible = !p.Visible;
    }
};

// Add columns to the DataGridView
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Title", "Title");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Author", "Author");

// Add data to the DataGridView
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Book 1", "Author 1");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Book 2", "Author 2");

// Set the control to fill the form
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

// Add the control to the form
this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
```

Panel control is added to the RowTemplate of the DataGridView, and set to be invisible by default. When a row is selected, the event handler for the RowStateChanged event is triggered, and the visibility of the panel is toggled. The panel can contain any information you want to display when the row is expanded.

Note that in this example, the panel is added to the first cell of each row. You may need to adjust the column index if you have a different layout for your DataGridView. Also, you can customize the appearance and behavior of the panel control to suit your needs.

Comment: I'm getting errors saying that dataGridView1.RowTemplate doesn't contain Controls and row.Cells[0].OwningRow doesn't have Template. Is there something I need to include or reference to make this work?